# Making a Grammar LL(1)

Tags: parsing, programming-languages, grammar, context-free-grammar, ll-grammar

I have the following grammar:

S → a S b S | b S a S | ε

Since I'm trying to write a small compiler for it, I'd like to make it LL(1). I see that there seems to be a FIRST/FOLLOW conflict here, and I know I have to use substitution to resolve it, but I'm not exactly sure how to go about it. Here is my proposed grammar, but I'm not sure if it's correct:

S-> aSbT | epsilon

T-> bFaF| epsilon

F-> epsilon

Can someone help out?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In his [original paper on LR parsing](http://web.archive.org/web/20170829205408if_/http://www.cs.dartmouth.edu/%7Emckeeman/cs48/mxcom/doc/knuth65.pdf), Knuth gives the following grammar for this language, which he conjectures "is the briefest possible unambiguous grammar for this language:"

> S → ε | aAbS | bBaS
>
> A → ε | aAbA
>
> B → ε | bBaB

Intuitively, this tries to break up any string of As and Bs into blocks that balance out completely.  Some blocks start with a and end with b, while others start with b and end with a.

We can compute FIRST and FOLLOW sets as follows:

> FIRST(S) = { ε, a, b }
>
> FIRST(A) = { ε, a }
>
> FIRST(B) = { ε, b }
>
> FOLLOW(S) = { $ }
>
> FOLLOW(A) = { b }
>
> FOLLOW(B) = { a }

Based on this, we get the following LL(1) parse table:

```
   |   a   |   b   |   $   
 --+-------+-------+-------
 S | aAbS  | bBaS  |  e
 A | aAbA  |   e   |
 B |   e   | bBaB  |
```

And so this grammar is not only LR(1), but it's LL(1) as well.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for your this helpful answer. I was also curious as to what you think about the grammar I proposed - it seems to me that it is also LL(1) and is not so different from Knuth's. I also can't see any strings for which it could fail.

Comment: @JohnRoberts- I don't think your grammar works correctly - for example, it can't get any strings that start with `b`.