# Can an LL(1) grammar have multiple rules that begin with the same non-terminal?

Tags: parsing, grammar, context-free-grammar, ll-grammar

Given a grammar G defined by

```
A -> Ca
B -> Cb
C -> e|f
```

Is this grammar LL(1)?

I realize that we could compress this down into a single line, but that's not the point of this question.

Mainly, can an LL(1) grammar have multiple rules that begin with the same non-terminal?

As a follow up question, how do I construct a parse table for the above grammar?

I've worked out the following:

```
FIRST(A) = {e,f}
FIRST(B) = {e,f}
FIRST(C) = {a,b}

FOLLOW(A) = {}
FOLLOW(B) = {}
FOLLOW(C) = {a,b}
```

I looked at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8496642/how-to-identify-whether-a-grammar-is-ll1-lr0-or-slr1), but didn't understand how they went from the FIRSTs and FOLLOWs to a table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The grammar you've given is not LL(1) because there is a FIRST/FIRST conflict between the two productions A → Ca and A → Cb.

In general, grammars with multiple productions for the same nonterminal that begin with the same nonterminal will not be LL(1) because you will get a FIRST/FIRST conflict. There are grammars with this property that are LL(1), though they're essentially degenerate cases. Consider, for example, the following grammar:

> A → Ea
>
> A → Eb
>
> E → ε

Here, the nonterminal E only expands out to the empty string ε and therefore, in effect, isn't really there. Therefore, the above grammar is LL(1) because there are no FIRST/FIRST conflicts between the two productions. To see this, here's the parse table:

```
     a  b  $
A    Ea Eb -
E    ε  ε  -
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Can you add some details about how to go from FIRST/FOLLOW sets to a parse table?

Comment: Wait, so we always know which rule to use in the parse table because this is LL(1)? I think I understand the use of FIRST sets in the table. I'm still uncertain about the roles of the FOLLOW ones.

Comment: @al92 Yes, the grammar is LL(1) because the table is unambiguous. We use FIRST sets exclusively in the A row to determine which productions to use when reading an `a` or `b`, and we use FOLLOW sets exclusively in the E row. Think of it this way - at some point, we need to expand out E to ε. If the current nonterminal is an E and we read an a or b, we know that the a or b really belong to another production and that the current E is getting in the way, so we should apply the production E -> ε to get the E out of the way. This happens because FOLLOW(E) = {a, b}.

Comment: Note that the language is LL(1), because there are LL(1) grammars for it (in fact, the language is regular `[ab][ef]`).

Answer (score 1):

I am solve your question in 2 case:

First case if the terminal is {a,b,e,f}
[image]

Second case if the terminal is {a,b,f} and e is epsilon

[image]

so no multipe entry this is LL(1).

For more information: 
look at this explanation and example below:

[image]

[image]

Best regards