# confusion in finding first and follow in left recursive grammar

Tags: parsing, recursion, compiler-construction, automata, pushdown-automaton

Recently I  faced the problem for finding first and follow

```
S->cAd
A->Ab|a
```

Here I am confused with first of A
which one is correct {a} , {empty,a} as there is left recursion in A's production  .
I am confused whether to include empty string in first of A or not 
Any help would be appreciated.
-------------edited---------------

what wil be the first and follow  of this ,,This is so confusing grammar i have ever seen

```
S->SA|A
A->a
```

I need to prove this grammar is not in LL(1) using parsing table but unable to do because i didnot get 2 entry in single cell.

Comment: I already mentioned to ask another question as it's too broad to include second part. Ask second afresh so that a broad answer for why this is not in LL(1) can be given! By the way, I have added left-recursion for you for the 2nd question...

Comment: Thanks @shekar suman .please help in this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27703952/how-to-prove-left-recursion-grammar-is-not-in-ll1-using-parsing-table

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly,you'll need to remove left-recursion leading to

```
S -> cAd
A -> aA'
A' -> bA' | epsilon
```

Then, you can calculate

```
FIRST(A) = a         // as a is the only terminal nderived first from A.
```

**`EDIT :-`**

For your second question,

```
S -> AS'
S' -> AS' | epsilon
A -> a

FIRST(A) = a
FIRST(S) = a
FIRST(S') = {a,epsilon}.
```

The idea of removing left-recursion before calculating `FIRST()` and `FOLLOW()` can be learnt [here](http://www.csd.uwo.ca/~moreno//CS447/Lectures/Syntax.html/node8.html).

Comment: Thanks shekhar suman for your nice answer . I understand your explanation.

Comment: Is grammar LL(1)? Can anyone explain??

Comment: Hi @John, sorry for the late reply. Please go through this question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/8496642/3482140, and let me know if you've difficulty evaluating whether the aforementioned grammar is LL(1) or not!

Comment: Thanks @Am_I_Helpful for your effort but I got my answer already.