# Epsilon(ε) productions and LR(0) grammars and LL(1) grammars

Tags: parsing, grammar, ll-grammar, lr-grammar

At many places (for example in this answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8496838/7571421)), I have seen it is written that an LR(0) grammar cannot contain ε productions.

Also in [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LL_grammar) I have seen statements like: An ε free LL(1) grammar is also SLR(1).

---

Now the problem which I am facing is that I cannot reason out the logic behind these statements.

Well, I know that LR(0) grammars accept the languages accepted by a DPDA by empty stack, i.e. the language they accept must have prefix property. [This prefix property can, however, be dealt with if we assume end markers and as such given any language the prefix property shall always be satisfied. Many texts like *Theory of Computation* by *Sipser* assume this end marker to simply their argument]. That being said, we can say (informally?) that a grammar is LR(0) if there is no state in the canonical collection of LR(0) items that have a shift-reduce conflict or reduce-reduce conflict.

With this background, I tried to consider the following grammar:

```
S -> Aa
A -> ε
```

[image]

*canonical collection of LR(0) items*

In the above DFA, I find that there is no state which has a shift-reduce conflict or reduce-reduce conflict.

So this grammar should be LR(0) as per my analysis. But it also has ε production.

Isn't this example contradicting the statement:

> "no grammar with ε productions can be LR(0)"

I guess if I know the logic behind the above quoted statement then I can understand the concept better.

---

Actually my main problem arose with the statement :

> An ε free LL(1) grammar is also SLR(1).

When I asked one of my friends, he gave the argument that as the LL(1) grammar is ε free hence it is LR(0) and hence it is SLR(1).

But I could not understand his logic either. When I asked him about reasoning, he started sharing post regarding "grammar with ε productions can never be LR(0)"...

But personally I could not think of any logic as to how "ε free LL(1) grammar is SLR(1)". Is it really related to the above property of "grammar with ε productions cannot be LR(0)"? If so, please do help me out.. If not, then should I consider asking a separate question for the second confusion?

---

I have got my concepts of compiler design from the dragon book by Ullman only. Also the knowledge of TOC from Ullman and from few other texts like Sipser, Linz.

Comment: Your start state has a shift-reduce conflict.

Comment: @MattTimmermans why do you say so? personally I feel there is no SR conflict based on the concept in Ullman text. The reduce is due to `A->.`. But there is no shift move. As for the `A`, I would say that it is goto and not shift...[I say this as per conventions in Ullman text]

Comment: After the first A is reduced, you are back in the start state and can reduce A again or shift to `A.a`.

Comment: @matt: after A is reduced, the next state is GOTO(S_0, A), which is not S_0. There is no reduction possible in that state.

Comment: Abhishek: for the future: why do you insist on asking questions like this on SO? It is not a programming question and it is irritating to not have MathJax available to format math. SO's argument for not enabling MathJax is that programming questions don't usually benefit from math formatting; whether or not one agrees with that assessment (I don't, as it happens), this is not a counterexample since it involves no programming. Asking it on [cs.se] would be more appropriate and a courtesy for prospective answerers who care about the appearance of their posts.

Comment: And heres an [answer from](https://cs.stackexchange.com/a/147827/4416) [cs.se] which covers the same ground.

Comment: @rici the link actually points to the root site... and not any answer... please can you check it once...

Comment: @rici should I delete this question here and repost it in cs.stackexchange? then you could answer the same there... Sorry as I used a reference from SO I thought that it would be appropriate probably to ask here. [I was wrong :(] sorry for that... once long ago I had asked a question on some stack exchange site... some one shifted the question to a more appropriate site... of StackExchange... is something like that possible here?

Comment: @AbhishekGhosh: no, leave it be. I answered here. But next time, please use [cs.se]. The Q could be migrated by a mod but they've got enough to do. The "link" in my other comment is actually two consecutive links; if you look closely you'll see they're separated by a non-linked space. The first one points at the answer.

Comment: @rici ok. I shall follow from next time... And sorry... Since the links are quite close, I actually did not notice the minute white-space between the two blue underlines.. yes got the answer...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A notable feature of your grammar is that `A` could just be eliminated. It serves absolutely no purpose. (By "eliminated", I mean simply removing all references to it; leaving productions otherwise intact.)

It is true that it's existence doesn't preclude the grammar from being LR(0). Similarly, a grammar with an unreachable non-terminal and an ε-production for that non-terminal could also be LR(0).

So it would be more accurate to say that a grammar cannot be LR(0) if it has a *productive* non-terminal with both an ε-production and some other *productive* production. But since we usually only consider reduced grammars without pointless non-terminals, I'm not sure that this additional pedantry serves much purpose.

---

As for your question about ε-free LL(1) grammars, here's a rough outline:

If an ε-free grammar is not LR(0), then there is some state with both a shift and a reduce action. Since the grammar is ε-free, that state was reached by way of a shift or a goto. The previous state must then have had two different productions with the same FIRST set, contradicting the LL(1) condition.

Comment: `if it has a productive non-terminal has both an ε-production and some other productive production.` I cannot get the meaning of this sentence... Might there is some sort of typo... because firstly the sentence reads weird... please can you have a look...

Comment: Sorry. I fixed it. "Productive" means that every non-terminal in the production can derive a sequence consisting only of terminals (or more accurately, without non-terminals).

Comment: got the point... I knew the concept ("productive") it seems... but knew it with a different name... "generating".